# How to rewrite/ reframe this question about possible mineral deposits to be Chemistry SE qualified?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

How to rewrite/ reframe this question about possible mineral deposits to be Chemistry SE qualified?

[**How to clean "reddish/ brownish" grime/ deposit marks from the silicone rubber lid gasket of a hot water Thermos Flask**?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/17240/how-to-clean-grime-marks-from-the-lid-gasket-of-a-hot-water-thermos-flask)

[image]

How could I make this question Chemistry SE qualified to get better recognition of said "mineral deposits" and hence a definitive or better solution for it?

The manufacturer said item is made of "Silicone Rubber" and I've got different suggestions from several sources about how to go about removing this and I can post that into the question as well.

I'd much rather have some "trained eyes" and "veteran experts" have a go at this. This should fall under Everyday Chemistry, but I'd rather do it right, then get grief for question slip ups.

Comment: My feeling is that for the most part it's alright. In my experience, these questions generally get a pretty good reception. I assume you aren't a chemist by training - generally for this kind of question what people like to see is that you include as much information as possible, which helps in identifying what the deposit is and what could possibly be done about it. It's sort of like going to see a doctor. You don't have to talk to them using medical jargon, you just need to describe your symptoms in detail.

Comment: You wanna migrate this here? I don't see a reason for this. You got answer and I doubt you'd get better one here.

Comment: @orthocresol - I'm composing more information than what is available on existing questions and answers and will post separately on Chemistry SE with details on what's been tried so far.